# Orthonormal basis with 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I have to create an orthonormalbasis $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ of the $\Bbb R^3$ with the vectors $a=(-1,1,2),\ b=(-2,0,0),\ c=(3,3,1)$

I know how to do that since there is Gram Schmidt but the exercise gives an extra information that confuses me:

$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{span}\{b_1\}&=\operatorname{span}\{a\}
\\\operatorname{span}\{b_1,b_2\}&=\operatorname{span}\{a,b\}\\
\operatorname{span}\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}&=\operatorname{span}\{a,b,c\}\end{aligned}$

Can someone help?

Comment: This extra information works well with Gram-Schmidt, $b_1=a/|a|,\,b_2'=b-(b\cdot b_1)b_1,\, b_2=b_2'/|b_2'|,\,b_3'=c-(c\cdot b_1)b_1-(c\cdot b_2)b_2$, ,$b_3=b_3'/|b_3'|$.

Comment: How is that _extra_? (:

Comment: Applying Gram-Schmidt to $a, b, c$ will produce vectors $b_1, b_2, b_3$ satisfying these properties. It's a feature of Gram-Schmidt. Note that this will not be true if you change the order, e.g. applying Gram-Schmidt to $b, c, a$ will produce $b_1, b_2, b_3$ that **do not** satisfy the given properties.